# Illustrate the conformal mapping

Tags: plotting, complex

Find the image of the circle $|z|=1$ by using the transformation

$$w=z+2+4i$$

Comment: Here's a start: `With[{z = Append[#, First@#] &@CirclePoints[60] . {1., I}}, Graphics[Through[{Line, Point}@ReIm[z + 2 + 4 I]]]]`, but why use Mathematica? You should aim to understand addition well enough to do this problem in your head.

Comment: It occurs to me that we often have people ask questions here thinking that the title "Mathematica" means the site is for mathematics questions.  Some might even think that the tag [mathematica-online] means one can ask such questions online.  It's not.  Mathematica is a software system implementing Wolfram Language.  Is your question about how to use this software?

Comment: @MichaelE2 oops, that's a fair point. To the author of the OP, please answer this question. I will undelete my response once the situation if clarified. Apologies to the rest of the users.

Comment: @bmf I just noticed that the OP's other question mentions Mathematica in the title. So probably it is. The only purpose in this (homework) exercise that I can see is to make sure the students can actually plot mappings before getting to the real conformal-mapping work. It hardly seems worth remarking that a translation is "conformal." Of course the PLZ in the other title suggests it was due at midnight, in whatever timezone. We're probably too late.

Comment: @MichaelE2 another fair point. Ok, so I brought back my response. I quite liked reading your train of thought, and especially the analysis of "We're probably too late"

Comment: @bmf Funny thing is, I'm working today on a demo of conformal mapping to use in class.  But instead of a circle, I was going to use a clipart elephant, I think.

Comment: @MichaelE2 please post the elephant. I am already upvoting it!!!

Comment: Has anyone kept a count of how many times this question was asked in the past week? Or under how many different user names? (On a less funny note, this incessant reposting outside the scope does seem to be an abuse of the forum.)

Comment: On the topic of "We're probably too late", there is [this now-classic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqG30j0FRW8)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau *Has anyone kept a count of how many times this question was asked in the past week? Or under how many different user names?* you are right for bringing this up, but I am inclined to answer "definitely less times than a certain post has been edited" (not sure how bad this joke is). Thanks for the video, made my day!

Comment: @bmf Yeah, that edit count surpassed even what I had been guessing. On a related note, I too await the conformally mapped elephant. (I hope that breaks no international anti-cruelty laws. Worst-case, maybe it can be finessed using the Finite Elephant Method.)

Comment: Conformal elephant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zNFP.png -- code to follow, maybe. It was harder to get what I wanted than I expected.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2.

Answer (score 20):

Meet Ellie, the Mesh Elephant:

```
Graphics[
 ellieGC = (* it's a GraphicsComplex[] *)
  ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/Mht5nzVi", "Text"]
 ]
```

[image]

The mesh will show the angle-preserving nature of conformal maps.

OP's example $f(z)=z+2+4i$ -- does it seem to you that the angles are preserved?:

```
With[{mapping = Function[z, z + 2 + 4 I], 
  scaledEllie = MapAt[3 # &, ellieGC, 1]},
 Show[
  Graphics@{Gray, Circle[]},
  Graphics[{Lighter@Lighter@Blue, scaledEllie}],
  Graphics[{Black, 
    MapAt[ReIm[mapping[# . {1, I}]] &, scaledEllie, 1]}],
  Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thickness@Small, Darker@Green]
  ]]
```

[image]

Taking a sip, $f(z)=z^2$:

```
With[{mapping = Function[z, z^2]},
 Show[
  Graphics@{Gray, Circle[]},
  Graphics[{Lighter@Lighter@Blue, ellieGC}],
  Graphics[{Black, MapAt[ReIm[mapping[# . {1, I}]] &, ellieGC, 1]}],
  Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thickness@Small, Darker@Green]
  ]]
```

[image]

Celebrating, conformally of course, $f(z) = \log z$:

```
With[{mapping = Function[z, Log[z]]},
 Show[
  Graphics@{Gray, Circle[]},
  Graphics[{Lighter@Lighter@Blue, ellieGC}],
  Graphics[{Black, MapAt[ReIm[mapping[# . {1, I}]] &, ellieGC, 1]}],
  Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thickness@Small, Darker@Green]
  ]]
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see, this is an elephant with complex behavior patterns.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much. I am very happy that I saw the comment. Even happier, I was the first upvote :-)

Comment: @MichaelE2 this is wonderful. +1 of course.

Comment: @MichaelE2 did you design the elephant as a `GraphicsComplex[...]`?

Comment: @ubpdqn Tx. I started with a clip art line drawing, closed some gaps and stuff, and used `ImageGraphics[]` to convert it to a `GraphicsComplex`. The line mesh I created, converted to a GC with ``NDSolve`FEM`GraphicsPrimitiveToGraphicsComplex``, and merged with the elephant outline. The hard part was computing the line segments. I feel embarrassed: There must be a function I couldn't find. `RegionIntersection` was slow and unreliable. So I wrote my own, which was a mess because of a stupid mistake halfway through. I may try to make a smaller one. The outline uses 3K+ points, the mesh lines ~2K.

Comment: @MichaelE2  thank you for description of how you made Ellie. Thank you for introducing me to new functions to explore. I would not have known even how to start. It is a wonderful way to show “amplitwist” and see angle preservation. I particularly like z^2 map. Thanks again

Comment: @ubpdqn You're welcome. That the tip of the nose lies on the imaginary axis makes the z^2 elephant just touch the negative real one. I also like how the unit circle running through the backside of Ellie is transformed to the imaginary axis running through the corresponding points in the Log[z] celebratory Ellie (and the tip of the nose is at a height of $i\,\pi/2$).

Comment: Looks like this got posted during one of my hiatuses. I might borrow it for some illustrations, and I'll upvote when I'm able. :)

Answer (score 6):

This is only meant to help you get started. I am hoping that you will look the commands in the documentation.

```
f[z_] := z + 2 + 4 I
fig1 = ComplexContourPlot[AbsArg[z], {z, -1 - 1 I, 1 + 1 I}, 
   ContourLabels -> All, ImageSize -> Full];
fig2 = ComplexContourPlot[AbsArg[f[z]], {z, -1 - 1 I, 1 + 1 I}, 
   ContourLabels -> All, ImageSize -> Full];
fig3 = ComplexContourPlot[ReIm[f[z]], {z, -1 - 1 I, 1 + 1 I}, 
   ContourLabels -> All, ImageSize -> Full];
GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2, fig3}]
```

> [image: conformalmap]

Answer (score 5):

Here we test four conformal mapping `w=z`, `w=z + 4 + 2 I`,`w=(z - 1)^2 + 5 - 2 I`, `w=1/(z - 1/2)^2 - 5 I`,use the `ParametricRegion` and add  `Abs[z] == 1` as a restriction.

```
mapping = 
  f |-> Region[
    Block[{w = f[z], z = x + I*y}, 
     ParametricRegion[{ReIm[w], Abs[z] == 1}, {x, y}]]];
Show[mapping[z |-> z], mapping[z |-> z + 4 + 2 I], 
 mapping[z |-> (z - 1)^2 + 5 - 2 I], 
 mapping[z |-> 1/(z - 1/2)^2 - 5 I], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]