# How can I do the same thing with mathematica?

Tags: field-theory

I would like to do the same thing that we can see from the picture but with Mathematica. The problem is that I am only an high-school student which try to do this. It would be appreciated if it could be kept simple.

[image]://i.stack.imgur.com/oBO7d.jpg

Comment: We just had a slew of [conformal mapping questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=conformal+mapping), which is a form of what you seek. My [Ellie](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266643/illustrate-the-conformal-mapping/266785#266785) is fairly easy to transform, but it was a lot of work. I'm not about to repeat it for your figure. (All the examples there are in terms of complex-number transformations, but it would be easy to revise them from $z = x + i y$ to $(x,y)$ terms.)

Comment: This is possible in Maple (see [transform](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plottools/transform) and [that example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cso8ui30mxij0a4/transform.pdf?dl=0)). 
It should be noticed that `transform` works with non-conformal mappings too.

Comment: { Cos[0.82 x] + Sin[0.33 y], 0.75 - Cos[0.33 x] + Sin[0.82 y] }, {x, 0, pi}, {y, -pi/2, pi/2}

Comment: I thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this is to start with your image and then warp it with ImageTransformation... since you didn't provide an image, I'll use a random one grabbed from the web. The two Sin functions control the warping of the regular grid lines in the original picture.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2kZh.png"];
ImageCrop[ImageTransformation[img, 
      # + {.02 Sin[ 20 #[[2]]], .02 Sin[ 20 #[[1]]]} &], {150, 160}]
```

[image]