# Plotting the image of $\Omega=\{z=x+iy \in \Bbb C \mid 1 \le x \le 2, 4\pi \le y \le 7\pi \}$ under $f(z)=e^z$

Tags: plotting, complex

I'm trying to plot the image of the the set $\Omega=\{z=x+iy \in \Bbb C \mid 1 \le x \le 2, 4\pi \le y \le 7\pi \}$ under $f(z)=e^z$, but I cannot find right function to do this from the docs. Could someone suggest how this could be achieved?

Comment: Generate `GraphicsComplex` (e.g. with `ParametricPlot`) of your rectangle, with whatever mesh lines you prefer and apply `MapAt[ReIm[mapping[# . {1, I}]] &, gc, 1]}]` to your graphics complex  `gc` as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266643/illustrate-the-conformal-mapping/266785#266785).

Comment: `Block[{z = x + I*y}, ParametricPlot[ReIm[E^z], {x, 1, 2}, {y, 4 π, 7 π}, Mesh -> 5]]`